# SQL Error (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x82\xA8\xE3\x83\xBC...'

Tags: string, heidisql

Hi I am trying to upload data to the Heidi SQL table, but it returned "SQL Error (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x82\xA8\xE3\x83\xBC...'".

This issue is prompted by this string - "ã‚¨ãƒ¼ãƒšãƒƒã‚¯ã‚¹ãƒ¬ã‚¸ã‚§ãƒ³ã‚º" , and the source data file has a number of special characters. Want to know if there's a way to override this, so that all forms of character could be uploaded?

My default setting is utf8 and I have also tried utf8mb4, but neither of them would work.

Comment: can you show your insert method? and table definition?

Comment: LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Q1 2020 Update Video Plays.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE `Video`.`20200416_UpdatedVideoPlay` 
CHARACTER SET UTF8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (`week`, `channel`, `game`, @ColVar3) 
SET `plays` = REPLACE(REPLACE(@ColVar3, ',', ''), '.', '.');

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you select the wrong file encoding in HeidiSQL's open-file dialog:

[image]

**Never select "Auto-detect"** - I wrote that auto-detection, and I can tell you it often detects the wrong encoding. Use the right encoding instead, which is mostly utf-8 nowadays.

Comment: Thansk! Sorry I should have clarified in the post, I have tried utf8 and utf8mb4, but both of them return the incorrect string error as well.

Comment: So you load the file via `LOAD DATA`? I was thinking you were loading it via HeidiSQL, reading your question. However, you will need to be sure about the file encoding. Use Notepad++ to load the file, and look into its lower right status bar to see the encoding.